# Is it possible to hide parts of an aframe entity?

Tags: three.js, aframe

Is there something equivalent to CSS's overflow: hidden in aframe? For example, can I constrain an entire  to be within a bounding  and have everything that is bigger than the box geometry to be hidden/invisible?

Answer (score 2):

There is clipping planes: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping.html

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_clipping.html

```
// ***** Clipping planes: *****
                var localPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 1, 0 ), 0.8 );
                var globalPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( - 1, 0, 0 ), 0.1 );
                // Geometry
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                        color: 0x80ee10,
                        shininess: 100,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                        // ***** Clipping setup (material): *****
                        clippingPlanes: [ localPlane ],
                        clipShadows: true
                    } );
                var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotBufferGeometry( 0.4, 0.08, 95, 20 );
                object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```